# How can I install git 1.9.4 or above on raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, git

I want to use emacs and magit on my raspberrypi. Magit requires git 1.9.4 or above. I tried this :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25088554/how-to-install-git-1-8-or-above-on-debian-wheezy

But the backport goes to git 1.9.1...

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build from source by executing the followings :

```
sudo apt-get install gettext
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-1.9.4.tar.xz
tar -xvf git-1.9.4.tar.xz   #or tar -xvf git-1*
```

If you check the site https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/ you can see many other distributions and you can choose any of them.

```
cd git-1.9.4/               #or cd git-*
./configure --prefix=/usr --with-gitconfig=/etc/gitconfig
make
sudo make install
```

You can check your version of git by :

git --version

Also check this topic : https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=103152